# Is there any better way for creating a dynamic HTML table without using any javascript library like Jquery YUI etc

Tags: javascript, html

**Dont worry we dont need to find out any bug in this code. Its working perfectly.**

My boss came to me and said "Hey just tell me whats the best of way of writing code for a dynamic HTML table (add row, delete row, update row).**No need to add any CSS. Just javascript. No jQuery library etc.** I was confused that in the middle of the project why he asking for some stupid exercise like this. What ever I wrote the following code and mailed him and after 15 mins I got a mail from him."

*I was expecting much better code from a guy like you. Anyways good job monkey.(And with a picture of monkey as attachment.)*

That was the mail. Line by line.

I want to reply him but before that i want to know about the quality of my code. Is this really shitty...!!! Or he was just making fun of mine.

I don't think that code is really shitty. Still correct me if you can. Code is working perfectly fine. Just copy paste it in a HTML file.

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>
                Crap work
        </title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_row()
{
        var table = document.getElementById('table');
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);     
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = ' <span onClick="edit(this)">Edit</span>/<span onClick="delete_row(this)">Delete</span>';
        cell3.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.innerHTML = '<span onClick="save(this)">Save</span>';
}


function save(e)
{
    var elTableCells = e.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("td");
    elTableCells[0].innerHTML=elTableCells[0].firstChild.value;
    elTableCells[1].innerHTML=elTableCells[1].firstChild.value;
    elTableCells[2].setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
    elTableCells[3].setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
}
function edit(e)
{
    var elTableCells = e.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("td");
    elTableCells[0].innerHTML='<input type="text" value="'+elTableCells[0].innerHTML+'">';
    elTableCells[1].innerHTML='<input type="text" value="'+elTableCells[1].innerHTML+'">';
    elTableCells[2].setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    elTableCells[3].setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
}

function delete_row(e)
{
    e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="display">
    <table id='table'>
        <tr id='id'>
            <td>
                Piemesons
            </td>

            <td>
                    23
            </td>   
            <td >
                <span onClick="edit(this)">Edit</span>/<span onClick="delete_row(this)">Delete</span>
            </td>   
            <td style="display:none;">
                <span onClick="save(this)">Save</span>
            </td>   
        </tr>   
    </table>    
        <input type="button" value="Add new row" onClick="add_row();" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Either way, I don't think I'd be happy working at a place where my boss called me "monkey". Or made me code up stupid little snippets with silly requirements for no reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some of the things I would fix:

1. Wrap it up properly. Functions in the global scope for something that's probably supposed to be re-usable = no-no.
2. Make it support more than one table per page
3. Make it configurable! Now you need to go in and edit the code just to add a new column.
4. Less innerHTML, more DOM. Try typing a quote into your textboxes and watch it break.
5. No setting event handlers with HTML attributes. At the very least use the "DOM level 0" properties (`.onclick`) or even better, `addEventListener` (and `attachEvent`)
6. Setting `display: block;` on a `<td>` is probably not what you want.

If I asked someone for a library to make an editable table, I wouldn't accept your implementation.

I'd give them the same list as above instead of sending them a picture of a monkey, though. Your boss is immature. The next time he randomly sends you an email asking for code, mail him back with a short description of you proposed features and implementation, and make him think the thing over first.

Answer (score 1):

You could've have split this up into separate functions which makes it both easier to read and easier to reuse.